# Ubuntu 14.04 Trying to combine two partitions without losing data

Tags: partitioning

When I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, I figured it would be simpler to have one partition with the O.S. and another for file storage. I think I was misguided. 
At the moment I have a 10 GB swap partition, an 8 GB filesystem [root] partition, and a 157 GB myfiles partition , which are all parts of an extended partition according to the Disks system utility [I don't have gparted]. Is there a way I can combine the myfiles and the filesystem partition without losing the data?

Thanks

Comment: This is a perfectly fine setup. I don't see what's wrong with it. Why change it ? It is common practice to get a root (/) partition and a home one, for example. You can have more.

Comment: Cool. I'm a bit of  a n00b, and I also do  a lot of stuff in python from the command line - also, the software centre automatically installs to the filesystem partition, but that shouldn't be too hard to change. Just wondering - how do I get to myfiles partition through the terminal then? If I can do that, I should be OK

Comment: I normally prefer 20 or 25GB for / (root) and use about 11GB of that. But have all data on another drive in a data partition. If swap is next to / you could combine those easily. But I never like moving / as it has higher risk as all data has to be copied to new location. Good to have backups.

Comment: solsTiCe: it surely shouldn't be too difficult to mount my filesystem partition into home? If it is possible, how could I do that?